# Why faster_than_requests returning null without setting an error?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am getting an error when I try to build this script. What could be causing this? Thank you

```
import faster_than_requests as requests

with open('infile.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

datalist=[]
for url in urls:
    data = requests.get2str2(url, threads = True)
    datalist.append(data.text)

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in datalist:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Traceback

```
line 8, in <module>
    data = requests.get2str2(url, threads = True)
SystemError: <built-in function get2str2> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `get2str2` takes a list object of URLS as input. And returns list of strings as output.

If the `urls` in your code is a list of URLS, then pass it directly without using for loop.

Something like:

```
resps = requests.get2str2(urls, threads = True)
```

The `resps` in above code, is list of responses returned for the list of URLS provided.

https://github.com/juancarlospaco/faster-than-requests#get2str2

Comment: I am not understanding. Could you explain a little more in depth?

Comment: What is "urls"  in your code? Is it a list of Urls?

Comment: Because the get2str2 function first parameter is a list type. But you are passing a url string type as input by looping the urls, which is wrong.

Comment: Avoid for loop, and pass "urls" directly as shown in answer.

Comment: Yes it is a list of urls with a newline separator

Comment: I am pasting the help documentation link in the answer.

Comment: Then directly pass the "urls" to the get2str2 function. No for loop required. The responses also a list object, which you can iterate and read the responses for your purpose.

Comment: So i will remove from datalist=[] through datalist.append?